# "Frame" depreciation from Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I am currently attempting to use [ScrollableGraphView](https://github.com/philackm/ScrollableGraphView) to implement a line graph into my app. I have struggled to use the line:

```
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: frame, dataSource: self)
```

which results in the error of

> Use of unresolved identifier '`frame`'

Was this **'use of frame'** removed for Swift 4? if so, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: ScrollableGraphView hyperlink is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **copy and paste** the below line to your code.

```
let frame = self.view.frame
```

Add the above line before :

```
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: frame, dataSource: self)
```

Thats it !.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume it correctly, you are tyring to initialize an instance of `ScrollableGraphView` inside a **view controller**. In that case, the view controller itself does not have a frame, but its view does:

```
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: view.frame, dataSource: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the frame.

```
let myFrame = CGRect(...)
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: myFrame, dataSource: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create CGRect for a frame argument:
let graphView = ScrollableGraphView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100), dataSource: self) 
or if you need that graph to be over whole screen you can use **UIScreen.main.bounds** for frame argument